# Accessing base memorystream [for read] in a binarywriter

Tags: c#, memorystream, binarywriter

I have a binarywriter that is backed by a memorystream as such:

```
BinaryWriter m_binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream(BUFFER_SIZE));
```

I want to get the base reader and read it into a byte array:

```
long DataLength = m_binaryWriter.BaseStream.Length;
byte[] MemoryStrData = new byte[DataLength];
int BytesRead = m_binaryWriter.BaseStream.Read(MemoryStrData, 0, (int)DataLength);
```

However, BytesRead is always 0 (and obviously MemoryStrData contains all 0's) . I have tried to use a BinaryReader to read the stream out of the base stream, but that resulted in the same thing. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You sure you're not after a `BinaryReader` and not a `BinaryWriter`.. ?

Comment: Yes, I am writing data into the binarywriter, but want access to a contiguous block (once it crosses BUFFER_SIZE).

Comment: You may be better off implementing custom class derived from `Stream` and implement whatever strange buffering/partial commit/logging (whatever you are after by reading random block from stream) inside of your class...

Answer (score 1):

Do you always know that the BinaryWriter will be backed by a MemoryStream?

If so, either keep a reference to the MemoryStream around, or cast the BaseStream as appropriate, and then use [`MemoryStream.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a byte array of the contents of the MemoryStream.

Comment: Yes, it will always be backed by a memorystream. When the buffer_size is reached I clear the binarywriter and dispose of the backend. Following this I re-create it. I don't think that the .ToArray() is supported in the Compact Framework, but I can check.

Comment: According to the documentation, it is supported, at least in the .NET 3.5 [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.90).aspx). I don't know much about the .NET Compact Framework though, so please confirm if you get the chance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. There is neither a member called .ToArray() nor a factory called MemoryStream.ToArray() in the compact framework. It is for that reason that I use .Read(). Now, I'm curious whether I have to initialize my MemoryStream with a backend byte array or not. I know there is an overload that has a 'bool WriteAble' flag. Does this need to be set? Another point of note is that when i do write to it the length of the memorystream DOES increase...

Comment: I don't understand why you couldn't find .ToArray(). The documentation says its supported in .NET Compact Framework 1, 2, and 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The BinaryWriter's current index seems to be different than it's backend stream's location! I figured that getting a handle to the basestream and then doing a .read(OutputArray,Index,Count) would be sufficient, but you need to do a seek on the BinaryWriter itself:

```
m_binaryWriter.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```